# LearnPython.org Tutorial (Exception Handling)

Tags: python, except

http://www.learnpython.org/page/Exception%20Handling

I am having trouble fixing the code to display the answer using `try/except`

Given code:

```
#Handle all the exceptions!
#Setup
actor = {"name": "John Cleese", "rank": "awesome"}

#Function to modify, should return the last name of the actor<br>
def get_last_name():
   return actor["last_name"]

#Test code
get_last_name()
print "All exceptions caught! Good job!"<br>
print "The actor's last name is %s" % get_last_name()
```

I was however able to get the correct display with the following code, however it does not use `try/except`

```
#Handle all the exceptions!
#Setup
actor = {"name": "John Cleese", "rank": "awesome"}
x = actor.pop("name")
#Function to modify, should return the last name of the actor<br><br>
def get_last_name():
   name = x.split(" ")
   last_name = name[1] #zero-based index
   return last_name

#Test code
get_last_name()
print "All exceptions caught! Good job!"
print "The actor's last name is %s" % get_last_name()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `last_name` key in the `actor` dictionary, so you will throw a [`KeyError`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyError) exception when you call `get_last_name()` on the last line.

```
def get_last_name():
   try:
      return actor["last_name"]
   except(KeyError):
      ## Handle the exception somehow
      return "Cleese"
```

Obviously instead of hard coding the `"Cleese"` string you could use the logic you wrote above to split the "name" field and derive the last name from it.

Comment: Thank You, I am completely learning python on my own and have never used try/except statements in previous programming.